# How to read registry from offline hives

Tags: c++, registry, computer-forensics

I am trying to build a basic digital forensics project in C++, so I need a way to read the registry from the hive files (`SYSTEM, SOFTWARE` etc.)

I am aware of the function `RegOpenKeyExW`, but as far as I can tell, this is for reading the registry on a live system, not for reading the offline hives.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The RegLoadKey function allows you to load an offline hive specifying where in the registry tree the hive will be located. There is also the RegLoadAppKey function which creates a registry tree that is not part of the normal global registry tree.

Note that with RegLoadKey you have to open the key after loading, RegLoadAppKey on the other hand returns a key via an out parameter.

Comment: Doesn't this method require adding the hives to the registry and then reading from live? I am trying not to edit the live systems registry, because that is very inefficient

Comment: Sure it requires making the hive part of the live registry set but that generally seems far preferable to me than trying to re-implement the registry API. Fewer points of failure, all the special cases handled already etc.